# Replace a word in a stream of words separated with underscore

Tags: cursor-motions, replace

Does anyone know a quick shortcut I can use to replace a word in a series of words connected with underscores?

Given:

```
Create_in_one_of_these_words
```

I want to make, where `|` is cursor:

```
Create_in_|_of_thse_words
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are anywhere on that line, you can try this:

- <kbd>0</kbd> - to go to the beginign of line
- `/one` - to jump to the word `one` (in this particular case even <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> would be enough - see `:help f`)
- <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> - this will delete everything between cursor and character pressed after `t` - so in this case everything till `_` - and since we used <kbd>c</kbd> it will leave you in insert mode - see `:help t`

Comment: IMHO this is not *a quick shortcut* but the general way. Afaik without customization, vim has no dedicated support for snake_case. Changing `set iskeyword-=_` has side effects (see for example [How do I change until the next underscore in Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/244040/how-do-i-change-until-the-next-underscore-in-vim#comment1725393_244070). There are more plugins to help you out [camelcasemotion](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) and [vim-wordmotion](https://github.com/chaoren/vim-wordmotion). However, I recommend to use the general way given here.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use [vim-textobj-variable-segment](https://github.com/Julian/vim-textobj-variable-segment) which along with [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user), will allow you to edit segments in snakecase and camelcase words. It provides `iv` and `av` text objects. This would allow you to do `fociv` to change you `one` in your example.